# Getting error while creating multiple get function inside single APIview class

Tags: django-rest-framework-simplejwt

My view.py

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class Sample(APIView):
http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']

```
def get(self, request):
    # Your logic for the default GET method
    response_data = {'message': 'Default GET method'}
    return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def get_fruits(self, request):
    # Your logic for a custom GET method
    fruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange"]
    response_data = {'fruits': fruits}
    return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def get_films(self, request):
    # Your logic for another custom GET method
    films = ["Saj", "don", "Man"]
    response_data = {"fnames": films}
    return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Urls.py

from django.urls import path
from .views import Sample
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Apiapp', Sample, basename='Sample')

urlpatterns = [
path('sample/get_fruits/', Sample.as_view({'get': 'get_fruits'}), name='custom-endpoint-1'),
path('sample', Sample.as_view(), name='get-fruits'),
#path('sample/films/', Sample.as_view({'get': 'get_films'}), name='get-films'),
]

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BhIz.png)